# Android Studio app is closed forcedly when I use WebView loadUrl function

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

When I add a `WebView`, the app is forcedly stopped. Actually, I don't know what is wrong with that. Build is successfully done. However, when I execute the built app, the app is forcedly closed. How can I resolve this problem? I'll add my code.

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intro">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Intro"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Intro.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```java
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private WebView webView;
    private Intent web = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
    }
```

fragment_intro.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.intro.IntroductionFragment">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post logcat error

Comment: 'Webview' is present in 'fragment_intro.xml', while in 'MainActivity' you are getting it from 'activity_main.xml'

Comment: You should paste your Webview inside your activity_main.xml as mentioned by @Nitish

Answer (score 0):

## in `MainActivity.java`

```java
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private WebView webView;
    private Intent web = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_intro);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
    }
```

**If it dont works please add **`IntroductionFragment.java`** in your code as your layout is using it:**
as
`tools:context=".ui.intro.IntroductionFragment`